# How do I clean this silicone tray?

Tags: baking, equipment, cleaning

I use this silicone muffin pan to cook things in the oven. It's supposed to be non-stick, but actually food sticks to it quite a lot.

Often I can just scrape dried food off with my fingers, but it's gradually building up brown stains and crusts that I can't remove even by scrubbing hard with a scourer. Is there some kind of trick to make it spotlessly clean again?

[image: dirty muffin pan]

Answer (score 8):

Try to put your silicon tray in boiling water for 3 to 5 minutes. I had the exact same problem and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

To clean burnt food from silicone bakeware, place the bakeware in the oven at 350 degrees for 10 minutes and fill a sink with water. Remove the bakeware from oven using tongs and wipe clean with water and a sponge.

or maybe try alcohol or a baking soda solution

Comment: 350 F or 350 C?